# Bootstrap Tour - How to close popup by clicking on close button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

By default bootstrap tour popups are closed by clicking anywhere and it seems that there is no way to change this behavior via options.

How can I make so that popups will close only by clicking on "Close" button?
How to find out what method, event closes popups there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
$(document).on("click", "html", function(event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("popover")) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming, when you said "close pop" you are referring to ending the tour.

I might be wrong, you said "*By default bootstrap tour popups are closed by clicking anywhere*". I have not seen this behavior on their website.

Bootstrap tour pop ups have **End tour** button on each pop up

Check [Demo](http://bootstraptour.com/)

Comment: You guessed right - it is popup itself. Not ending the tour.

I also seen that on their site it doesn't close by clicking anywhere. Hoped that somebody else encountered such problem and there won't be need to explore it.

The problem is that after implementing it on our site - popups are closed by clicking anywhere.